# Where does fprint store fingerprints

Tags: d-bus, fingerprint

I am using fingerprint scanner with [`python-validity`](https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity) driver. According to `fprintd(1)`, fingerprint data is stored in `/var/lib/fprint/` after enrolling a fingerprint with `fprintd-enroll`. But I have this folder empty, although scanning works properly.

What I want is to share fingerprint data between two users, because one of them is always getting fingerprint recorded better. If fingerprints were stored as files, I could just create a symlink between them. But it doesn't seem to be the case.

So where can I find fingerprint data for a given user and how can I copy it to be used by another user?

OS: `Linux 5.11.11-arch1-1 x86_64`
Fingerprint reader: `ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc. Metallica MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader`

```
$ fprintd-list $USER
found 1 devices
Device at /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Fingerprints for user <USER> on DBus driver (press):
 - #0: WINBIO_ANSI_381_POS_RH_INDEX_FINGER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question on Google while trying to solve the same problem. fprintd does in fact store fingerprints in `/var/lib/fprint/`, though maybe it stores fingerprints differently for your fingerprint sensor.

With regards to copying a registered fingerprint to a different user, that is technically not supported by fprintd; as not all fingerprint sensors support that, and the developers intend for a fingerprint to uniquely identify the user. This is explained in a code comment [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/fprintd/-/blob/master/src/device.c#L2226).

With that said, I wanted to be able to use the same finger to authenticate multiple users, so went and found a way to copy my fingerprint to a separate user account on my computer. However, it's not as simple as just copying the finger print file. With the way the data format works, you need to register your username inside the fingerprint data file. It's not possible to just symlink the file, and libfprint does not provide any sort of command-line tool for this.

To solve this, I have written a [python script](https://github.com/JustinLex/fprintd-copy-finger) that interfaces with the fprintd library in order to copy fingerprint files. Try it and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the config file at `/etc/fprintd.conf`? You may find a different path in it.

Comment: No, didn't find anything useful there: `[storage] type=file`