# How to backup and restore fprintd fingerprints?

Tags: backup, fingerprint

I have configured `fprintd` on Arch Linux by following the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fprint) and enrolled fingerprints with `fprintd-enroll`. According to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644237/where-does-fprint-store-fingerprints) the fingerprints should be stored at `/var/lib/fprint/` and `/etc/fprintd.conf` doesn't tell me anything. The only file in `/var/lib/fprint/` is `strongbad/synaptics/590ac910c956/7` with size 118 bytes and does not look like a fingerprint to me

```
FP3^A^@^@^@synaptics^@590ac910c956^@^A^Gstrongbad^@^@FP1-20240227-7-2FA486E8-strongbad^@^@^@^?F^K^@^AFP1-20240227-7-2FA486E8-strongbad^>
```

How do I backup and restore the fignerprints?